# "Clipboard access is not allowed" when attempting to set clipboard text

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

Never worked with clipboard before, trying to do a rather simple thing. Here is the code:

```
try
{
    if (!Clipboard.ContainsText())
    {
        Clipboard.SetText(text);
    }
}
catch (SecurityException se)
{
    MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
}
```

(the code is run when button is pressed)

Throws "Clipboard access is not allowed" exception. I know that in order to access clipboard, user has to allow access through a pop-up. The pop-up appeared a while ago and does not anymore. I think I denied permission by clicking "No" back then.

Is there a way to force the security pop-up to show up every time to give user a choice of allowing or not allowing clipboard access? At this point application would always catch the mentioned exception, while a user has to be able to change their mind upon every click (if this is at all possible).

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Solution turned out to be rather simple. Right click -> change permissions in the Silverlight menu was enough (removing "Clipboard" permission), no need to reinstall Silverlight, thank god =) that would be ugly

Comment: Life saviour!!! That would be stupid to install whole silverlight for anything like that. Your solution solved the issue for me. Thumbs up!!!

Answer (score 0):

In windows7 , you can search for silverlight in the program search box, which open up the Microsoft Silverlight Configuration window,
Choose permission tab, then change the necessary permission
You dont have to uninstall the program.